# Get code from jQuery HTMLLIElement object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that appends some code to the elements. The problem is, when I use jQuery's selector (`$('.wdcl')`), it works fine but when I create a new element and send it to the function, it won't work.

Here is the code embeded in the HMTL file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu li a').click(function(){ 
            //...
            var $newItem = $('<li id="TEST" class="widget color-blue"></li>').appendTo($(columns).first());
            obj.doWidget($newItem.get(0));            
            return false;  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

And here is the code in the .js file (the addWidgetControls function is called from somewhere else. I want to also run the doWidget function whenever the menu items add another widget):

```
addWidgetControls: function () {
    var func = this.doWidget;

    $('.widget', $('.column')).each(function () {
        func(this);
    });
},

doWidget: function (wid) {
    alert(wid);
        //...
    }
```

so if I'm using the wrong syntax, please let me know, otherwise, please tell me how can I print out the source from the passed object to see what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: `$newItem` is a jQuery object; wrapping it inside `$(...)` is useless.

Comment: It seems to work anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/ePaFm/. Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to pass to `obj.runFunc`. `$newItem.get(0)` returns javascript object/version of the element `$newItem`. You want the js object or the html string `<li id="TEST" class="wdcl"></li>`?

Comment: I want to pass the jQuery object to the javascript function. So I want the javascript object. It seems fine but I want to get the source of the js object to see what the problem is.

Comment: Do you want `.eq(0)` instead of `.get(0)` then?

Comment: It didn't work either. Please take a look at the edited question. I added more code to explain the full situation. Thank you.

Comment: So doesn't anyone know how to get the code from that object? I need to get it done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE9, I used `$newItem.get(0).outerHTML` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on your `obj.doWidget()` function. If it suspects that the given element is a jquery element you shouldn't use `get(0)`

`get()` [Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object. So it isn't a jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: The problem is that none of these work. I'd like to know how to get the objec's source so that I can see what is the problem.